# Display raw memory contents in GDB TUI

Tags: linux, gdb, tui

Is there a way to configure a TUI window to display raw memory contents?

I mean instead of viewing the memory with `x/20x 0x7fffffffe270` just have a window that displays and automatically updates the contents of the memory in that location (or if that's possible, just display the memory contents line `x/20x $sp`).

Something like this:

```
0x7fffffffe270: 0x00000000  0x00000000  0x55555250  0x00005555
0x7fffffffe280: 0x00000000  0x00000000  0x55555070  0x00005555
0x7fffffffe290: 0xffffe390  0x00007fff  0x00000000  0x00000000
0x7fffffffe2a0: 0x00000000  0x00000000  0xf7df4b25  0x00007fff
0x7fffffffe2b0: 0xffffe398  0x00007fff  0xf7fca000  0x00000001
0x7fffffffe2c0: 0x55555169  0x00005555  0xffffe6f9  0x00007fff
0x7fffffffe2d0: 0x55555250  0x00005555  0x3cae816d  0x8acc2837
0x7fffffffe2e0: 0x55555070  0x00005555  0x00000000  0x00000000
0x7fffffffe2f0: 0x00000000  0x00000000  0x00000000  0x00000000
0x7fffffffe300: 0xf9ce816d  0x7533d7c8  0xa91a816d  0x7533c789
```

Comment: I've [extended gdb](https://github.com/ssbssa/gdb/releases) with a few TUI windows via python, one of them is a memory window. It can be activated with `memory 0x7fffffffe270`.

Comment: Thanks, but I think your build is for Windows right?

Comment: I only provide Windows builds, but the source code works for Linux as well.

Comment: Thanks @ssbssa. I got stuck with the build though. Something to do with bison and/or YACC.

Comment: You don't have bison installed?

Comment: I didn't have it installed, but I installed with with `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install -y bison`, but it still failed afterwards. I will try to send you the error details via private chat.

Comment: Continue here: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253642/display-raw-memory-contents-in-gdb-tui